# How do you specify stylesheets for spcific media using ASP.NET Themes?

Tags: asp.net, themes

This is a question brought up in a local user group mailing list at dot.net.nz ...

> I when I create an XHTML page
>   old-fashioned way, I used to use the
>   following syntax for my CSS
>   declarations:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” media=”screen” href=”css/screen.css” />

<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” media=”print” href=”css/printer.css” />
```

> Now, since I code using ASP.NET 2.0
>   and beyond; I fell in love with the
>   Themes. However, I don’t know how to
>   do the same thing using Themes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define media in the CSS file:

```
@media print
{
    p
    {
        ...
    }

    ...put styles here.
}
```

Comment: So then I would have a screen.css which encapsulates the style within @media screen { ... } and a printer.css when encapsulates the styles within @media print { ... }

I guess that makes sense.

Comment: This is not the most elegant solution for mobile devices where bandwidth is a concern and now the device has to download the styles for all media types.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the media type inside the stylesheets. For example, printer.css:

```
@media print
{
    /* Print CSS rules here */
}
```